# Solving $(\sqrt{2})^x+(\sqrt{2})^{x-1}=2(2\sqrt{2}+1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponentiation, radicals

I'm in stuck with this simple equation.
$$(\sqrt{2})^x+(\sqrt{2})^{x-1}=2(2\sqrt{2}+1)$$

This is my solution:
$$\begin{align}(\sqrt{2})^x+(\sqrt{2})^x(\sqrt{2})^{-1} &=4\sqrt{2}+2 \tag{1}\\[4pt]
2^{x/2}+2^{(x-1)/2}&=2^2\cdot 2^{1/2}+2^1 \tag{2}\\[4pt]
{\frac x2}+{\frac {x-1} 2}&=2^{2+\frac 1 2}+2^1 \tag{3}\\[4pt]
{\frac {2x-1} 2}&={\frac 5 2}+1  \tag{4}\\[4pt]
{\frac {2x-1} 2}&={\frac 7 2} \tag{5}\\[4pt]
{\frac {2x-1} 2}-{\frac 7 2}&=0 \tag{6}\\[4pt]
{\frac {2x-8} 2}&=0 \tag{7}\\[4pt]
2x&=8 \tag{8}\\[4pt]
x&=4 \tag{9}
\end{align}$$

But the solution must be $x=4.33$. I can't find the error.

Is here someone who can help me? Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Your incorrect step starts from here.

$$2^{\frac x2}+2^{\frac{x-1}{2}}≠\frac x2+\frac{x-1}{2}$$

Because, this is **not a equality:**

$$2^a+2^b ≠ a+b$$

---

You can do one of the correct solutions as follows:

$$(\sqrt 2)^{x-1}(\sqrt 2-1)=4\sqrt 2+2$$

$$(\sqrt 2)^{x-1}=\frac{4\sqrt 2+2}{\sqrt 2-1}$$

$$(\sqrt 2)^{x-1}=\frac{(4\sqrt 2+2)(\sqrt 2+1)}{(\sqrt 2-1)(\sqrt 2+1)}$$

$$(\sqrt 2)^{x-1}=(4\sqrt 2+2)(\sqrt 2+1)$$

$$(\sqrt 2)^{x-1}=6\sqrt 2+10$$

$$\frac {x-1}{2}=\log_2(6\sqrt 2+10)$$

$$\cdots \cdots \cdots$$

Comment: Good work ${}{}{}$, I'd give you an upvote but I used all of mines for today

Comment: @SomeGuy It seems that I don't know anything but a little bit of MathJax and a little bit of math on this site... Each time I learn new rules from the comments.  For example, until a few days, I thought there was no limit to asking questions on the site.  The limit was 50.  I mean, I learned from you that upvote is limited :) with that logic, down-vote should also be limited.:)

Comment: thanks you, I undertood where was the problem. But I don't know how to solve this kind of of equation, like $2^{\frac x 2}+ 2^{\frac x 2}*2^{\frac {-1} 2}$

Comment: @Ciao you're welcome. I added the right solution for you to my answer.

Comment: @Ciao Check out the solution and feel free to ask again if you don't understand.

Comment: I'm sorry, I searched some info on google, like videos on youtube and some mathematical articles, but I don't find the solution. Exacly how you semplify from $(\sqrt{2})^x+(\sqrt{2})^{x-1}$ to $(\sqrt{2})^{x-1}(\sqrt{2}-1)$? The next semplifications steps that you do, I understand. The last one you wrote:   $(x−1)/2=log2(62–√+10)$ ,  it will be $x=2log2(6(\sqrt{2}+10)+1$

Comment: @lonestudent Downvotes are limited, they are tracked in the same $40$ vote counter as upvotes

Comment: @Ciao take another example $$2^x-2^{x-1}=2^{x-1}×2-2^{x-1}=2^{x-1}(2-1)$$